# Run Python script in one docker-compose container in another

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

I want to run a python script in a docker container from another docker container within a docker-compose environment, here is an abstraction of the `docker-compose.yml` file:

```
app:
  build: ./app
  volumes:
   - ./app:/app
   - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
  links:
   - container1
   - container2
   - python_container
  ports:
   - "13000:3000"
  working_dir: /app
  command: npm install
  entrypoint: /entrypoint.sh

container1:
  image: container1:version
  ports:
   - "3005:3005"
  volumes:
   - ./volume:/volume

container2:
  image: container2:version
  ports:
   - "3004:3004"

python_container:
 image: some_image
 volumes:
  - ./scripts_volume:/scripts_volume
```

Is it possible to run a python script in de `python_container` from within the `app` container? I have a node application that needs to run python scripts for which we created a docker 'runtime' container with all dependencies prebuilt.

I already tried mounting de docker socket, however when i try to run

```
docker-compose run python_container python scriptname.py
```

it says:

```
Can't find a suitable configuration file in this directory or any parent. Are you in the right directory?
```

If it is possible, what is the best approach?

Regards